# How to set title page with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where the client will set the name that will appear in the `<title>` of the page.
Wanted to know how best to do this with AngularJS.

It will define and save thus leaving the `<title>` Custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add ng-model in your input

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="title">
```

This one in your controller

```
 document.title = $scope.title;
```

Comment: worked ok, but as the customer would change that title via <input>?

Comment: Yes ! I ll edit for you

Comment: nice! yo're welcome. hugs